# Crash reporting with Flurry and Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, crash-reports, flurry

I'm using Flurry Analytics and Xamarin.iOS to write an iOS application. I use bindings from [here](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/FlurryAnalytics) (Flurry SDK 4.2.3). In FinishedLaunching() method override I call:

```
Flurry.SetCrashReportingEnabled(true);
Flurry.StartSession(FlurryAPIKey);
```

Everything compiles and launches successfully.
After real data appears in Flurry dashboard I see many errors with the same call stack:

```
0   Fines                               0x0049e500 -[FlurryPLCrashReporterConfig symbolicationStrategy] + 4334767
1   Fines                               0x0049e61c -[FlurryPLCrashReporterConfig symbolicationStrategy] + 4335051
2   Fines                               0x0049e908 -[FlurryPLCrashReporterConfig symbolicationStrategy] + 4335799
...
30  Fines                               0x00685c53 -[FlurryPLCrashReporterConfig symbolicationStrategy] + 6331394
31  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38a90919 <redacted> + 140
32  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38a9088b __pthread_start + 102
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x38a8eaa4 _thread_start + 8
```

What does this call stack mean? And what is the correct way to track all unhandled exceptions with Monotouch and Flurry?

Answer (score 0):

From flurry FAQ:

`My strack traces are de-symbolicated/obfuscated.

    For iOS applications we have partnered with Plausible Labs to create an innovative technology that re-symbolicates most of the stack trace in the application itself so you do not need to provide a desym file to use the service. We also provide ways to upload your desym file to improve your stack trace detail and to support Android applications. On the stack trace detail page, there is the option to upload either the dsym file (iOS) or the Proguard mapping file (Android). Once you upload the file, we’ll try and symbolicate the stack traces for you.`

dsym file means the file with extension .dSYM it should be in the folder with your .ipa build. Also dSYM file is uniq for every new build don't forget to save somewhere the dsym file.

Comment: The problem is not on the desymbolication stage. The errors itself are sent not correct. Seems like Mono specific.